# What does this mean "Narrowing a primitive truncates the high order bits"

Tags: java, primitive-types, narrowing

What does this mean "Narrowing a primitive truncates the high order bits"

Comment: be careful with the sign of the number...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

E.g. if you cast long to int you are discarding the higher bits of the long.

```
Short  -> Byte
0x00FF -> 0xFF
256    -> -128
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short, carefully-chosen answer.

```
public class Narrow {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int i;
  short s;

  i = 32768;
  s = (short) i;
  System.out.println("int of " + i + " becomes a short of " + s);
 }
}
```

i is 2^15, or one bigger than the MAX_VALUE of short.

Java will reply `int of 32768 becomes a short of -32768`