# Narrowing after Widening in Java

Tags: java

Suppose that I hava a `String` object reference and I assign it to an `Object` reference.This would implicitly perform `widening`.

```
Object o = "Hello World"
```

Now we cannot use any `String` methods on `o`. My Question is will there be any loss of data because of this typecasting, as in C++ where data would be lost if we cast a `float` into an `int`.

If I cast `o` back to `String` explicitly will I be able to access the actual `String`.

There are a lot of methods in Java which has `Object` type variable as an argument.So I can pass any type of object ref to this argument. Can I convert this object back to the original by narrowing it explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For objects, you're simply casting the *reference*. The object (`String`) still remains intact.

When you pass a `String` to a method call, you're simply passing the reference to it (as occurs when you encounter a return value). You can check and recast using

```
if (o instanceof String) {
   String s = (String)o;
}
```

and safely use that string (note that if you're doing this a lot it may point to an incorrect object modelling, but that's another issue)

Note that you also talk about floats/ints, and these are distinct from the above, since they're Java *primitives*, not references. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777905/what-does-this-mean-narrowing-a-primitive-truncates-the-high-order-bits) for a discussion on casting primitives. Briefly, you will lose data here.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a method which returns an object of Object class, you can return string and infact, you can return any Java object.  Without any purpose, simply casting affects the performance (and more due to the immutability of the String). Infact, without casting to Object also, you can make of the methods of Object class. If you would like to know more of immutability affects, you can refer [Introduction – Immutable Nature – Comparison](http://way2java.com/string-and-stringbuffer/introduction-immutable-nature-comparison/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you have a `String` object, you can. But you can even test it runtime:

```
Object o = "Hello there!";
if (o instanceof String) {
    String s = (String) o;
    System.out.println("String length: " + s.length());
} else {
    System.out.println("Something else: " + o.getClass().getName());
}
```

Actually, testing is a good practice, if you don't want unexpected `ClassCastException`s.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose that I hava a String object reference and I assign it to an
>   Object reference.This would implicitly perform widening

No. This does not perform widening, it performs *casting*

> Will there be any loss of data because of this typecasting

No. The Object is still a String, regardless of the upcast. It can be *downcast* back to a String at any point.

Narrowing and Widening are defined with respect to primitive and reference conversions.
Upcasting and Downcasting (as you have used them) are defined with respect to identify conversion.